# Как я могу использовать метод Activity в Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть `Activity` в которой есть метод `write()`(Он находиться в p`ublic class ThreadConnected extends Thread` ), который посылает данные по bluetooth. 
В `Fragment` есть `Button` , и при нажатие на нее должен вызываться метод write(), который находиться в `Activity`.
Как такое можно реализовать , и возможно ли вообще ?

```
public class SocerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimerDialogFragment.onTextViewNum {




 ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;
 /*....*/


public class ThreadConnected extends Thread {    // Поток - приём и отправка данных

    private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
    private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;
    private String sbprint;
    public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        connectedInputStream = in;
        connectedOutputStream = out;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() { // Приём данных
        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                int bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                String strIncom = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                sb.append(strIncom); // собираем символы в строку
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n"); // определяем конец строки

                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {

                    sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // Вывод данных

                        @Override
                        public void run() {



                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



/*
***Конопка для отправки данных**
*/
*
public void BtnRefresh(View v){
        if(myThreadConnected !=null){
            String someData = "SomeData";
            byte[] someDataToByte = someData.getBytes();
            myThreadConnected.write(someDataToByte);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно. Во фрагменте есть ссылка на активити. Получите её, скастуйте к нужному типу и вызывайте метод. Типа как-то так: `((MainActivity)getActivity()).write()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб дело в том, что у меня несколько Activity, и Fragment тоже используется в них

Comment: Тогда создайте интерфейс с вашим методом, реализуете его во всех активити и кастуйте к интерфейсу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не могли бы Вы навести пример, если не трудно?

Comment: Что то типа такого: В отдельном файле public interface A{ void write()}. Далее все активити его должны реализовать. Типа MainActivity implements A. Потом фо фрагменте ((A)getActivity()).write()

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оновил вопрос, так как я не точно указал где именно находиться метод write();

Comment: Судя по коду у вас метод write вообще к активити не привязан. Т.е., вроде, можно просто поток запустить из фрагмента, не трогая активити. Если это не так - покажите как вы этот метод из активити вызываете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

В `Activity`:

```
public void myMethod(){
        if(myThreadConnected !=null){
        String someData = "SomeData";
        byte[] someDataToByte = someData.getBytes();
        myThreadConnected.write(someDataToByte);
    }
}
```

Во фрагменте:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).myMethod();
```

По идее, должно сработать.